# show that $f_n$ converges uniformly

Tags: real-analysis, uniform-convergence

Let $f(x) = \frac{nx}{1+nx}, x\in [0, \infty).$

1. Find $\lim _{n \to \infty}f_n(x) = f(x).$

When $x = 0, f_n$ converges to $0$.

When $x\in(0,\infty)$, I claim that $\lim_{n\to\infty} f_n(x)=1.$

Proof: Let $\varepsilon>0$. Let $M\in N$ such that $M>\frac {1}{\varepsilon x}$. Then, for $n\ge M, |\frac {nx}{1+nx}-1| = |\frac {-1}{1+nx}|<\frac {1}{Mx} <\varepsilon.$

2. Does $f_n \to f$ uniformly on $[0,1]$? Justify your answer.

Yes. Let $M > \frac 1{\varepsilon}.$ Then, for $n\ge M$, $|\frac {nx}{1+nx}-1|=|\frac {-1}{1+nx}|\le \frac {1}{1+n} <\frac 1n\le \frac 1M<\varepsilon $ for all $x\in(0,1].$ 
But, here, when $x=0,$ $f_n$ converges to $0$. So, it seems that $f_n$ still depends on whether $x= 0 $ or otherwise. How can we justify this?

3. Does $f_n \to f$ uniformly on $[0,\infty)$? Justify your answer.

"No" because $|\frac {-1}{1+nx}|\not \le \frac {1}{1+n}$ (it now depends on whether $x\le 1 $ or $x>1$). But, I don't know how to prove formally by using negation of the definition. I appreciate any hint.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: What do you know about the uniform limit of a sequence of continuous functions?

Comment: Wrong direction when you say $\left| \frac{-1}{1+nx} \right| \le \frac{1}{1+n}$; in fact, $\left| \frac{-1}{1+nx} \right| \ge \frac{1}{1+n}$ for $0 \le x \le 1$.

Answer (score 2):

The sequence $(f_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ doesn't converge uniformly to $f$ on $[0,1]$ (or on $[0,+\infty)$), because when a sequence of continuous functions converges uniformly to a function $f$, then $f$ is continuous too. But your function $f$ isn't continuous.

Comment: Ok. Then, if $x\in (0,1],$ does $f_n$ converges uniformly ? and if $x \in (0, \infty),$ does $f_n$ not converge uniformly?

Comment: @ShuyinKim $f_n$ does not converge uniformly on $(0, 1]$, which you can prove based on the fact that $f_n(\frac{1}{n}) = \frac{1}{2}$.  Same argument on $(0, \infty)$.  It *does* happen, though, that $f_n$ converges uniformly on $[1, \infty)$.

Comment: @DanielSchepler Thanks!